# How can I change the size of the error message pop ups?

Tags: customization, error

How can I change the size of the error message pop ups? At the moment as shown in the printscreen, I am not able to see the whole text of the message.

[image]

Comment: How do you call the popup? `operator.report`?

Comment: Is this a question about scripting, are you writing your own addon? Or is this about an issue with an existing addon you are using?

Comment: It is about an existing addon (Make Clothes). After modeling, when I press the Make Clothes button, that error message appears, but as you can see, not all of the message text is shown. So I wonder how I can manage to see all of it?